# Fb.api post to user wall only on login

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like to use fb.api to post on logged user, but just once. If I put this

```
var params = {};
params['message'] = 'gegeegeggegall! Check out www.facebook.com/trashcandyrock for more info.';
params['name'] = 'gegeggeeg - gegegege';
params['description'] = 'Check out Tegegegeg! Win merch by playing and reccomending to your friends.';
params['link'] = 'http://www.bblblba.com';
params['picture'] = 'http://summer-mourning.zoocha.com/uploads/thumb.png';
params['caption'] = 'Tgegegegeeg';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
  }
});
```

It posts to users wall everytime he refreshes the site?

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

What is triggering the FB.api call? If it's just code within a  tag then it's going to run as soon as the browser gets to that point.

You could possibly store some sort of cookie value or something after the FB.api call then check it on page load, but that seems like more work than is probably needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want him to post it only once, ever?

If so, you're going to need to create a "state". In order to do this, you could do it client sided (with cookies), or server sided (with a database).

Create a boolean variable named "posted", and store it in a cookie or in a database (since you're using javascript, it's probably easier to use a cookie).

```
var posted=getCookie("posted");
if(!posted)
{
  //call the FB.api();
  setCookie("posted", true, duration);
}
```

Definition of setCookie and getCookie: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I would rather see if it is possible to do it without cookies? Let's say, I need to post on the wall of the user at the exact moment,  that he clicks the button to allow my app to post on his wall. So I want to post on his wall when he accepts my game and plays it for the first time. Am I missing something here? Should I do this differently?

Comment: In this case, you are going to have to add an event to that button that will execute your code (as a function).

But, if the user plays the game multiple times are you going to post to their wall each time they play? If not, you are going to need to create a "state" as some point. Using this approach, it would be best to create the state server side and keep track of which walls you've already posted on, and don't post on them again.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a FQL query and check to see if the message has already been posted by querying the stream table with your app id.  Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="postToWall();return false;">Post To Wall</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId  : '**yourAppID**', status : true, cookie : true, xfbml  : true });

  function postToWall() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        FB.api(
          {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT post_id, message from stream where app_id = **yourAppID** and source_id = me()'
          },
          function(response) {
            if(response.length == 0){
              FB.ui(
              {
                 method: 'feed',
                 name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                 link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                 picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                 caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                 description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
                 message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
              },
              function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                   alert('Post was published.');
                } else {
                  alert('Post was not published.');
                }
              }
             );         
            }
            else { 
              alert('User already posted this message');
            }
          }
        );
      }
    } , {perms:''}); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```